# Want to Make a UI Similar to theChive app

Tags: android

I am wanting to make an Android app where the UI is similar to the UI of theChive's Gallery.  Have been playing with Android for maybe 10min.  I have been searching through all kinds of tutorials, but nothing seems to be what I am after.
I want to learn how to make a scrolling list.  Each item in the list will have a picture on the left, and some text to the right.  Each item should be able to be 'Clicked' on and take them to another screen with more details.
I don't know if this 'Item' should be a button, textview, widget, gallery, etc...  If I can figure the best practice for doing this, I think I can figure out the rest from there.  Can anyone point me in the right direction of an article/blog/tutorial?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can make a custom ListView or GridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to play more with android and google.

[Tutorial1](http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/01/android/android-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)

[Tutorial2](http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-listview-with-iconsimages-and-sharks-with-lasers/)

Comment: Thanks.  It's hard to search for something when you don't really know the keywords you should be searching for.